# How to get the path param value in java AWS Lambda function

Tags: java, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

URL: `/test/{userName}`

In *AWS Lambda function*, How can I get the `{username}` path parameter value. 
I am calling lambda function through *AWS API gaetway*.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using AWS integration type:

Use a [mapping template](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference) to send $input.params('username') property in the request body to your Lambda function.

If you are using AWS_PROXY integration type:

You can access the path parameters via the "pathParameters" property of the incoming [event](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format).