# How to access path variable (GET) in AWS Lambda function

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I am working aws lambda with API gateway. for my compare-yourself-api resource I created a sub resource called field (please refer screenshot).

when I am testing it, I can see the request uri: /compare-yourself-api/test1.
I can see test1 in request but not sure how to access that field in my functionhandler. I tried `Map<String,String>` as input in place of object but still the same issue. I was getting empty value.

my output from Gateway Method Test screen is:
"{}   Hello from Lambda!"

Empty curly braces with out any object.

Here is my lambda function.

```
package com.amazonaws.lambda.demo;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<Object, String> {

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Object input, Context context) {
        context.getLogger().log("Input: " + input);


        // TODO: implement your handler
        return input+"   Hello from Lambda!";
    }

}
```

Please suggest me how can I get the pathvariable in Lambda function handler java.

[image: Gateway resources and methods]

Comment: I found solution from other similar question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41762462/how-to-get-the-path-param-value-in-java-aws-lambda-function .          
Sorry..

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter is passed as query string. You can find it from request. Something like this [How to pass a querystring value from AWS API Gateway to a Lambda C# function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46050894/how-to-pass-a-querystring-value-from-aws-api-gateway-to-a-lambda-c-sharp-functio)